# Could not load 'plugins\HelloWorld.jar' in folder 'plugins' org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: commands are of wrong type

Tags: java, server, minecraft, bukkit

Hi Y`all i recently start coding in java to make minecraft plugins and that sort of thing i just started  doin this type of thing about a month ago and learned how to do all of the fun stuff in eclipse to start my project, i have looked at a bunch of tutorials but all of them basicly dont work because i get this error every time, if anyone could help that would be fanstastic.

**This is the error message when i load it up**

> [16:52:22] [Server thread/ERROR]: Could not load
> 'plugins\HelloWorld.jar' in folder 'plugins'
> org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: commands are of wrong
> type
> at org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile.loadMap(PluginDescriptionFile.java:969)
> ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
> at org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile.(PluginDescriptionFile.java:240)
> ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
> at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:165)
> ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
> at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:138)
> [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
> at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:350)
> [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:202)
> [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:775)
> [spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_251] Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
> java.util.Map
> at org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile.loadMap(PluginDescriptionFile.java:951)
> ~[spigot-1.14.4.jar:git-Spigot-cbd1a1b-009d8af]
> ... 7 more

Please help how do i fix this!!

(btw i would link the plugin.yml and Main, and all that stuff but idk how so if someone can reply to this and tell me how to do that i can post that too,  thank you any help is very aprreciated)

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft avid here. Check your YML format through http://www.yamllint.com/ or any other YML validator.

Take an example:

Wrong format

```
name: HelloWorld
main: com.company.HelloWorld
version: 1.0
commands:
  hello:
  description: testing   //description should take more indent than above because it's inside region
  usage: /helloworld
  aliases: [helloworld]
```

Correct format

```
name: HelloWorld
main: com.company.HelloWorld
version: 1.0
commands:
  hello:
    description: testing   //correct one
    usage: /helloworld
    aliases: [helloworld]
```

Comment: hey amn thank you so much for the helo, i have tried that though idk cuz i looked this up and i saw soething about that and tried it but it didnt work, but thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Nvm dude you did it!!! i swear i tried that before and it did not run but you fixed it thank you so much and have a blessed exsistance